# How to get the latest employee record in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee table with columns like emp_id, firstname, lastname,  region_id, status and effective_date.

Employee Table can have multiple entries for same employee with different effective dates and statuses.

Employee can have two statuses 'Leaver' and 'Joiner'.

```
id     emp_id    firstname     region    status     effective_date  
1       1         James        Asia      Joiner     1-Jan-2012 
2       1         James        UK        Leaver     1-Aug-2012
3       1         James        USA       Joiner     1-Aug-2012
4       1         James        Asia      Leaver     1-May-2012
5       1         James        UK        Joiner     1-May-2012
6       1         James        USA       Leaver     1-Sep-2012
```

With the above data in employee table, If i want to get the latest record of james as on 1 Jan 2012, I would get record with id = 1,

If i want to get the latest record of james as on 1 May 2012, I would get record with id = 5

If i want to get the latest record of james as on 1 Aug 2012, I would get record with id = 3,

If i want to get the latest record of james as on 1 Sep 2012, I would get record with id = 6

Following query correctly gives me latest record

```
SELECT 
        emp_id, 
        MAX(effective_date) AS latest_effective_date
FROM 
        EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY 
        emp_id
```

But then how do I get the other columns such as firstname , region etc.

If I put them in select clause or group by clause, I dont just get the latest record but the other records as well.

Comment: Could you explain this please? "If i want to get the latest record of james as on 1 Aug 2012, I would get record with id = 3" why not 2?

Comment: @Sebas. Sure, James is moving from region UK to USA on 1 Aug 2012. So, If I need to see where is James as on 1 Aug 2012, it has to return USA and not UK. Hence the record with id = 3 and not id = 2.

Comment: well then your entire logic is to be reviewed, your own query returns "correctly last record" only by chance. I'm off this topic now, you have analytic problems to solve.

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT  
    e.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by emp_id order by effective_date DESC) r
FROM  
    EMPLOYEE  e)
WHERE r = 1;
```

Above will get you a record with maximal effective__Date for every distinct emp_id.

Your second requirement of returning record for given date should be fullfiled by this query:

("status ASC" - will take care of taking "Joiner" status if there is also "Leaver" for the same date.)

```
 SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT  
    e.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by emp_id order by effective_date DESC, status ASC) r
FROM  
    EMPLOYEE  e
WHERE effective_date <= '<your desired date>')
WHERE r=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to inner join the query you already have back to your Employee table to limit the records:

```
SELECT  Emp.*
FROM    Employee Emp
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Emp_ID, MAX(effective_date) AS latest_effective_date
            FROM    Employee
            GROUP BY Emp_ID
        ) MaxEmp
            ON Emp.Emp_ID = MaxEmp.Emp_ID
            AND Emp.Effective_Date = MaxEmp.latest_effective_date
```

Comment: I cannot suggest an improvement/correction based on this feedback. Why is it not working, does it not run? Does it run but not with the results you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE emp
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) AS id
        emp_id, 
        MAX(effective_date) AS latest_effective_date
FROM 
        EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY 
        emp_id) AS employee_1 on emp.id = employee_1.id
```

Comment: Ids may not be generated in sequence. Users may enter record for 1-sep-2012 in system before inserting the record for 1-Aug-2012 (i.e. forecasting).

Answer (score 1):

the query you've entered doesn't necessarily return record with ids 3, 5, 6 like you stated before, because in this case:

```
2       1         James        Asia      Leaver     1-May-2012
3       1         James        UK        Joiner     1-May-2012
```

effective_date is equal for both rows and it would probably return record with id 2 and not 3.

try adding time to your table or adding time to your effective_date column, this way you'll be able to get the latest result from a user in a determined date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT  
  MAX(id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY effective_date DESC) id,
  MAX(emp_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY effective_date DESC) emp_id,
  MAX(firstname) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY effective_date DESC) firstname,
  MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY effective_date DESC) status,
  MAX(effective_date) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY effective_date DESC) effective_date
FROM Employee GROUP BY firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem : GET Employee records joined latest in the company

Solution : 
Step 1. Get latest date when employees recently joined a company 
Step 2. Get records of all employees who joined on that date

```
select * 
from EMPLOYEE 
where effective_date in (
    SELECT MAX(effective_date) AS latest_effective_date 
    FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY emp_id
);
```