# Oracle view join to table very weird slow issue

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I have a table `order`, which is very straightforward, it is storing `order` data.

I have a `view`, which is storing currency pair and currency rate. The view is created as below:

```
create or replace view view_currency_rate as (

  select c.* from currency_rate c, (

  select curr_from, curr_to, max(rate_date) max_rate_date from currency_rate
  where system_rate > 0
  group by curr_from, curr_to) r

  where c.curr_from = r.curr_from 
  and c.curr_to = r.curr_to
  and c.rate_date = r.max_rate_date
  and c.system_rate > 0

);
```

nothing fancy here, this `view` populate the latest currency rate (curr_from -> curr_to) from the `currency_rate` table.

When I do as below, it populate 80k row (all data) because I have plenty of records in order table. And the time spent is less than 5 seconds.

***First Query:***

```
select * from 
 VIEW_CURRENCY_RATE c, order a
where 
 c.curr_from = A.CURRENCY;
```

I want to add in more filter, so I thought it could be faster, so I added this:

***Second Query:***

```
select * from 
 VIEW_CURRENCY_RATE c, order a
where 
 a.id = 'xxxx'
 and c.curr_from = A.CURRENCY;
```

And now it run over 1 minute! I totally have no idea what happen to this. I thought it would be some oracle optimizer goes wrong, so I try to find another way, think of just the 80K data can be populated quite fast, so I try to get the data from it, so I nested the SQL as below:

```
select * from (
 select * from 
 VIEW_CURRENCY_RATE c, order a
 where 
 c.curr_from = A.CURRENCY
)
where id = 'xxxx';
```

It run damn slow as well! I running out of idea, can anyone explain what happen to my script?

**Updated on 6-Sep-2016**
After I know how to 'explain plan', I capture the screen:

Fist query (fast one with 80K data):

[image]

Second query (slow one):

[image]

The slow one totally break the view and form a new SQL! This is super weird that how can Oracle optimize this like that?

Comment: 1. Use modern methods of searching for the maximum. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786087/how-to-get-the-latest-employee-record-in-oracle/10786828#10786828  2. See "explain plain" for query.  3. Yes, view poorly optimized.

Comment: Perhaps you have an index on `currency` but not on `id` in your `order` table? How fast does `select * from order where id = 'xxxx'` run?

Comment: @mathguy Yup, `id` it is a index. result will come out within a second.

Comment: @Mike thanks, I just found that `explain plan` is super useful. and your 'modern method' somehow it work, although it is weird, when I select the new view (from your suggestion) only, it is slower than mine one, but once I join the view with other table, it is super fast.

Comment: @GMsoF Does the first query return *all* the rows in 5 seconds or just the first N?  If your IDE only grabs the first N rows your query comparison may not be fair.

Comment: @JonHeller Due to too many data, I couldn't show all rows in SQL developer (GC limit over), and export all data to excel will be limited by the disk write speed as well. So I used a trick, I `select count(*)` for both script, first one indeed finish in 5 seconds and second one exceed more than 10 minutes. Maybe the actual time spent is not accurate but the proportion should be roughly there.

Comment: 1. Is there an index on currency_rate.curr_from ? Perhaps better would be a unique index on (curr_from, curr_to, rate_date). 2. try to rewrite condition as `nvl(a.id,0) = 'xxxx'`

Comment: Try on the inner query of the third query adding the hint `/*+ NO_MERGE NO_PUSH_PRED */`. `NO_MERGE` should stop it combining the 2 levels of query. `NO_PUSH_PRED` should stop the optimisation of the inner query seeing the `id ='xxxx'` predicate. I'm not saying this will give the correct optimisation but hopefully will give the original optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Mike solution, I re-write the script, and it is running fast now, although the root cause is not determined, probably due to the oracle optimizer algorithm working in different way that I expect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem relates to the plan of second query. because it uses of nest loops inplace of hash joint.
at first check if _hash_join_enable is true if it isn't true change it to true. if it is true there are some problem with oracle optimizer. for test it use of USE_HASH(tab2 tab1) hint.

Regards
mohsen

Comment: Both plans have at least one hash join so they must be enabled.